# Azure Cosmos DB - CreateDatabaseAsync - Resource Not Found

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-2.0

I have been developing an application with Azure Cosmos DB using the Emulator with  good success - I've been able to create the database & collections and add documents to the collections as well as read those documents. the trouble now is that I've tried to swap the emulator out for a live instance of Azure Cosmos DB and I am getting an error whilst trying to create the database.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.
```

note this is while trying to create the database not find it, the exact code is as follows

```
public async Task CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await client.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(_databaseId));
        }
        catch (DocumentClientException e)
        {
            if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = _databaseId }); // Throws Not Found Here!
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(e.StatusCode);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Edit

- I have not connection string, only an endpoint and access key - I am connecting with

  client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(_endpoint), _key);
- I am targeting the DocumentDB API
- the output of `UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(_databaseId)` is dbs/digivate_clients_0_blogging
- full exception content below

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.
ActivityId: 8df27b98-ed3b-4aed-ac9a-cfb0e6374aa4
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ClientExtensions.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.GatewayServiceConfigurationReader.<GetDatabaseAccountAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Routing.GlobalEndpointManager.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.GatewayServiceConfigurationReader.<InitializeReaderAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.d__267.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.d__55.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.d__100.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.d__104.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Digivate.Blogging.DocumentDb.DocumentDBRepository`1.<CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync>d__11.MoveNext() in I:\Digivate.Blogging\Digivate.Blogging.DocumentDb\DocumentDBRepository.cs:line 94
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Digivate.Blogging.API.Controllers.PublishedBlogPostsController.<_canLoadDocuments>d__6.MoveNext() in I:\Digivate.Blogging\Digivate.Blogging.Api\Controllers\PublishedBlogPostsController.cs:line 154
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Digivate.Blogging.API.Controllers.PublishedBlogPostsController.d__1.MoveNext() in I:\Digivate.Blogging\Digivate.Blogging.Api\Controllers\PublishedBlogPostsController.cs:line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

thanks

Comment: Can you please update your question and include the following information: 1) Connection string for your live Cosmos DB account (please obfuscate account name/key obviously); 2) What is the API your Cosmos DB account is targeting (it seems you're targeting DocumentDB but wanted to be sure); 3) Output of  `UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(_databaseId)`; and 4) More details about the exception.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thanks for your help  - I've added the details you requested above

Comment: Thanks Brett! 2 more things: 1) Does your endpoint look something like `https://account-name.documents.azure.com`? 2) Can you also tell the version of SDK you're using?

Comment: service endpoint (plus read & write endpoints) : `https://nz-co-playfulpukekos.documents.azure.com/` Am using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 1.6.0 (I was using 1.5.0 earlier but updated to see if it fixed the issue)

Comment: Thank you! Let me try out your code.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but unfortunately couldn't do so. I was able to create databases properly.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, any chance you could share the code for your reproduction, so I could compare to my code? I’m guessing I’ve done something incredibly stupid but I’m a bit stumped.

Comment: Sure thing....I ended up creating a console application. Please see the code here: https://gist.github.com/gmantri/2f28244ff1e0e0a2594f3a28b5fdbcc9. I used SDK version 1.6 as well. HTH.

Comment: Thanks again - I ended up deleting the cosmos db account and creating a new one which now works - I'll put it in the don't know, doesn't matter basket.

Comment: In case you get here as I did. I had forgotten to white list the environment that I was testing in the firewall settings and received the exact error with the exact same code as above.