# EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos preview 3 - Not Found Error

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use the new EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos Preview 3 package in an ASP.NET Core website, but I keep getting an error back when trying to Create the DB.  I can't seem to find any documentation to give me an idea of what is causing the error.

In my Startup.cs file in the ConfigureServices method I have the following code:

```
// Configure EntityFramework - CosmosDB
services.AddDbContext<EFContext>(options => options.UseCosmos(
    authKeyOrResourceToken: ServiceFactory.GetDbKeySecret(_config, (_hosting.EnvironmentName != "LocalDev")),
    serviceEndPoint: _config.GetValue<string>("CosmosDb:Endpoint"),
    databaseName: _config.GetValue<string>("CosmosDb:DatabaseID")
));
EFContext efc = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<EFContext>();
efc.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync().Wait();
```

When it gets to the last line I get the below error (stack trace):

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Storage.Internal.CosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsOnceAsync(DbContext _, Object __, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Storage.Internal.CosmosDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreatedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

And with Fiddler the detailed response is: "{"code":"NotFound","message":"Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.\r\nActivityId: 6aed2df0-abe8-4e93-b468-b3188005fcb5, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.1.0.0"}"

I have checked and double checked all the values in my config are correct and match to my CosmosDB account in Azure, but I still can't figure out what is causing this error.

Has anyone run into this and have a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's happening when trying to create the DB?  The error message seems to indicate a document with the specified id does not exist.

Comment: Definitely during DB creation, or more correctly during checking if the DB exists (apparently).  I get the same message whether the DB exists or not (I tried without one then created a DB by the same name in the portal and tried again with the same results).  There is no document involved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue previously posted ([Azure Cosmos DB - CreateDatabaseAsync - Resource Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881893/azure-cosmos-db-createdatabaseasync-resource-not-found)) where someone had the same kind of issue and resolved it by deleting the DB and recreating.  I tried the same thing and found that my code works as expected.

I guess there was some error during creation that was never reported (or I missed an error message somewhere) with the original CosmosDB Account creation.  So if anyone is getting similar message, try recreating your account.